# Modify the [MCVE] page to emphasize [edit]-ing question body

Tags: feature-request

The  [[MCVE]-page:](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) does a fairly good job of suggesting clarifications that include a `[MCVE]` but it doesn't emphasize the fact that any code should go in the  question body and *not* in Comments. Example of newbie using Comments for code:
[Generating a vector consisting of random samples from a PDF distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52230867/generating-a-vector-consisting-of-random-samples-from-a-pdf-distribution)

Comment: I'd think that it's not so much fault of the MCVE page as much as the user was just responding to the comment "You'll need to post some code examples showing what you've tried before you ask for help" without even clicking on the link about MCVE, but maybe that's just my cynicism.

Comment: Well, I do generally post links to [edit] and [MCVE] these days but I think the system should already be doing it for us.

Comment: While we’re at it: the MCVE page also doesn’t say that the code should be put in the question itself rather than on an external site, and it doesn’t say that formatted text should be used rather than images of code.

Comment: @Xufox I thought you were being sarcastic for a moment, but then I realized that plenty of people really do those things :(

Comment: @Aran-Fey Someone actually only had a JSFiddle link in their question, and when I requested them to include an MCVE, they argued that they have already provided one — after all there’s a JSFiddle link! I thought, _have they really read the MCVE page? It clearly states that they should include the code in the question! Oh. It doesn’t…?_

Comment: I've seen novices not get it after being given a [mcve] comment, but then get it after their question is closed. Presumably that means the MCVE close reason _does_ explain all of this (including the extra point by @Xufox) well enough, so it should just be a matter of copying the same wording to the first paragraph of the help page.

Comment: (Sure, the user does _eventually_ get it, which is nice… but their first experience asking a question on the site isn't going to feel too positive, and for a user who's actually trying to learn how to do things right, that's pretty bad. Also, they wasted other people's time trying to explain something to them that shouldn't have been needed.)

Comment: I think this is as much a UX design problem as anything: the edit control is a tiny gray word, not an obviously clickable button.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313935/make-the-share-edit-close-flag-buttons-more-obviously-buttons-please on SE Meta.